# Error in Laravel 8. Undefined constant App\Models\Person::token

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Person extends Model
{
    private static $token = 'PWPu3Wl71N39x3M';

    public static function getToken() {
        return self::token;
    }
}
```

How can I get token?

I don't want made constant, I need private static $token = 'PWPu3Wl71N39x3M';

Comment: Try: `return self::$token;`. Note the extra `$`.

Comment: correct self::token first to `self::$token` , then `$person = new Person();` and `$token = $person->getToken()`

Comment: @Win what's the purpose of creating an instance of Person if method is static?

Comment: @StewieSWS good question ^_^

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details which can be done with a [mre]. Please [edit] your question to add these details into it or we may not be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

```php
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Person extends Model
{
    /** @var string */
    private const TOKEN = 'text';
    
    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public static function getToken(): string
    {
        return self::TOKEN; // text
    }
}

/**
 * Usage
 */

Person::getToken(); // text
```